# UITabBarItem appearance for UIControlStateHighlighted

Tags: ios, uitabbaritem

I have this code in my AppDelegate.m file under `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` so that I can have a custom font.

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                        [UIColor grayColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                        [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham-Medium" size:10], UITextAttributeFont, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                        [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                        [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham-Medium" size:10], UITextAttributeFont, nil] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

The font change works as expected, but I get this output in the Debug console:

`button text attributes only respected for UIControlStateNormal, UIControlStateHighlighted and UIControlStateDisabled. state = 1 is interpreted as UIControlStateHighlighted.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `UIControlStateHighlighted` to `UIControlStateSelected`

Comment: Remember the +1 and check

Comment: Just did that. Thanks